# SQL Server triggers deleted vs inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

In a SQL Server `after update` trigger, how would this work if the `DELETED` is already in the `INSERTED` ? Or what exactly does the `deleted` pseudo table contain?

```
SELECT * 
INTO #ModifiedData 
FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM DELETED
     EXCEPT
     SELECT * FROM INSERTED) ModifiedData;
```

Comment: DELETED will contain old data (which was before update), INSERTED the new one

Comment: that's correct, thank u

Comment: There are many discussions of triggers (waiting for you to find and read them) that address the issue of finding rows that are actually changed. Good developers should write code that does not perform "useless" updates, making this sort of logic unnecessary, but sometimes this sort of thing is needed. Perhaps next time just experiment and see what happens - this is trivial to test and you will learn more by doing so.

Answer (score -1):

So the way that SQL works is that it creates two tables. The first table, the deleted table. The second table is the inserted table. You can create your temp table, but it will be drop right after the trigger is out of memory. So it would help if you moved it to a permanent table. As a dba, I would highly advise against this method as it can cause a lot of data on high traffic tables. And you may have an update that does not change any data.

Answer (score -2):

the INSERTED table has the new updated values and the DELETED table has the old value (before update)

so this
SELECT * FROM DELETED EXCEPT SELECT * FROM INSERTED

will get only the actual updated rows.

example :
updating column with the same value
this row will be only in the INSERTED table.

Comment: The `Inserted` table will **only ever** contain any rows that were updated by the SQL statement that caused the trigger to fire in the first place ..... this `SELECT ... EXCEPT...` is totally useless .....

Comment: how the SELECT ... EXCEPT...  is useless, it will get only the changed values

example : updating row with the same values then this row will be only in the INSERTED table.

Comment: It's useless because the `Inserted` pseudo-table **already** contains only the changed / updated rows.....

Comment: Inserted table already contains the updated rows, that's true.

but not always the case, you might update a value with the same value, so you want to exclude that (get only the updated with new values rows) and that's when it'll be useful